# Command line arguments passing in python

Tags: python, command-line, python-3.x, arguments

Hi I am new to Python and have currently copied following script:

```
# filename is printer.py
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg    # the zeroth element is the module name
raw_input("press any key")    # a trick to keep the python console open
```

I am trying to get the arguments followed by the module name.
But running this code gives me following error:

```
U:\printer.py
    File "U:\printer.py", line 6
      print arg # zeroth element is the module name
              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong here?
I am using Python 3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3 [`print`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) is a function:

```
print(arg)
```

Answer (score 5):

As noted by others, in python3, `print` is a function:

```
print arg
```

is now:

```
print(arg)
```

Also, `raw_input` is gone and replaced by simply `input`.  (in py2k, `input` would `eval` the string from the commandline, but it won't do that in py3k).

---

Finally (and maybe most importantly), have you considered `argparse`? (*untested code follows*)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo',nargs='*',help="What a nice day we're having")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.foo)
```

Comment: Also, "press any key" is a lie, whether you're using `raw_input` or `input`.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 no longer has a `print` keyword, but a `print` function.

Try instead

```
print(arg)
```